# Ruby - How do you add data into a nested array?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, user-input, nested-loops

I'm relatively new to Ruby and I'm trying to design a code that will help me with work.

What I would like the code to do is allow the user to input the "invoice numbers" for each day of the week starting on Monday, then when the user has finished entering the invoice numbers, the program should ask how many hours were worked for each day. Then, I would like for the program to divide the amount of hours worked by the amount of invoice numbers inputted for each respective day and output the "billable time" in a format like this:

say Monday worked 10 hours and you inputted invoice #123 and #124

The program should output the following -

```
Monday
#123 - 5 Hours
#124 - 5 Hours
```

but I would like for this to happen for every day of the week. I'm assuming I'll need to use a nested Array but I'm just confused as to how to go about adding the entries from the user and having the program know when to "move" to the next day to add the next set of entries.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
days = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat","Sun"]
entry = Array.new
days.each do |day|
    while entry != "ok"
      puts "Enter PR # for " + day
      puts "/n Type 'ok' when finished"
      entry.each do |input|
        input << gets.to_s.chomp
      end
    end
end
```

Essentially I would just like for the program to recognize that the user is done inputting entries for that day by typing "ok" or something so that it can move from Monday to Tuesday, etc.

In a perfect world... at the end of the sequence, I would like for the program to combine the values of all similarly named invoice numbers from each day into one result (i.e. if invoice #123 applied on Monday and Tuesday, the program would add the sums of the billable hours from those two days and output the result as one total billable amount.)

Thank you in advance for any assistance with this as the knowledge that comes with it will be deeply valued!!

Comment: It is not clear whether you want help in modelling your data, or in how to ask for confirmation from the user. Ask only about a single problem in one question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion- I'm trying to find the most efficient method of storing user input MULTIPLE times in a nested array, then confirm when the user is done and move to the next point in the array and repeat the process until the user finishes inputting data for the last point in the array. (i.e. Days[Monday[Pr-20, Pr-21, Pr-22],Tuesday[Pr-22, Pr-23, Pr-24]) Etc. Let's start with that. I can ask the part about manipulating the data later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might collect the needed information as follows.

```
DAYS = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
```

```
def invoices_by_day
  DAYS.each_with_object({}) do |day, inv_by_day|
    prs = []
    loop do
      puts "Enter PR # for #{day}. Press ENTER when finished"
      pr = gets.chomp
      break if pr.empty?
      prs << pr
    end
    hours =
      if prs.any?
        puts "Enter hours worked on #{day}"
        gets.to_f
      else
        0
      end
    inv_by_day[day] = { prs: prs, hours: hours }
  end
end
```

Suppose

```
h = invoices_by_day
  #=> { "Mon"=>{ prs: ["123", "124"], hours: 21.05 },
  #     "Tue"=>{ prs: ["125"], hours: 31.42 },
  #     "Wed"=>{ prs: ["126", "127"], hours: 68.42 },
  #     "Thu"=>{ prs: ["128"], hours: 31.05 },
  #     "Fri"=>{ prs: [], hours: 0 },
  #     "Sat"=>{ prs: ["129", "130"], hours: 16.71 }
  #     "Sun"=>{ prs: ["131"], hours: 55.92 } }
```

Then you could display this information in various ways, such as the following.

```
h.each do |day, g|
  puts day
  if g[:prs].empty?
    puts "  No invoices"
  else
    avg = (g[:hours]/g[:prs].size).round(2)
    g[:prs].each { |pr| puts "  ##{pr}: #{avg}" }
  end
end
```

```
Mon
  #123: 10.53
  #124: 10.53
Tue
  #125: 31.42
Wed
  #126: 34.21
  #127: 34.21
Thurs
  #128: 31.05
Fri
  No invoices
Sat
  #129: 8.36
  #130: 8.36
Sun
  #131: 55.92
```

As a rule it is good practice to separate the data collection from the manipulation of the data and the presentation of the results. That makes it easier to change either at a later date.

I use [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) with `break` for virtually all looping. One advantage of `loop` is that employs a block (unlike `while` and `until`), confining the scope of local variables created within the block to the block. Another advantage is that it handles `StopIteration` exceptions by breaking out of the loop. That exception is raised by an enumerator when it attempts to generate an element beyond its last value. For example, if `e = 3.times #=> #<Enumerator: 3:times>`, then `e.next #=> 0`, `e.next #=> 1` `e.next #=> 2`, `e.next #=> StopIteration`.

Comment: Hey Cary- When I try to call the invoices_by_day function as is it doesn't seem to go beyond Monday for me. After I type the hours worked for the PR, it loops back and says Mon again. Not only that, but I was ideally trying to input an amount of hours worked for the day as a whole, and then divide that amongst the PR numbers inputted (i.e. worked 10 hours for day, split between PR-1, PR-2, PR-3 would output 3.33 hours for each PR #. I hope that makes sense. Thank you so much for taking the time to help with this!!

Comment: Please see my edit and tell me if it still needs work.

Comment: Cary- Thank you!!!! This did exactly what I was looking for! Now I just have to sit and stare at this code along with your commentary for the next couple of weeks so I can figure out what's going on!! LOL!! You're a champion!!

Comment: Cary- quick question. Can you please advise me as to why using a nested array would not be an effective solution for this program? What made you opt for the method that you did?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by a "nested  array". Is that instead of a hash? You could save the data as, for example, `data = [[["123", "124"], 21.05], [["125"], 31.42], [["126", "127"], 68.42],...]`, so pr's and hours for Wednesday would be `data[3][0] #=> ["126", "127"]` and `data[3][1] #=> 68.42`, but I'm sure you'll agree that a hash (my hash `h`) is much more descriptive and easier to understand: `h["Wed"] #=> { prs: ["126", "127"], hours: 68.42 }`. You may be impressed by my code but as you gain experience you will come to realize that it's really nothing special.

Comment: Yes I was referring to using a hash instead of an "array within an array". Forgive me on the terminology, but exactly how you wrote it in the comment above was how I initially visualized gathering the data. data = [[["123", "124"], 21.05], but I definitely agree that your hash is cleaner and easier to look at for sure.  I'm still trying to comprehend hashes and their utilization, especially in a real world example such as this.

Comment: Cary- if it's not too much to ask, would you mind inserting comments for ```inv_by_day[day] = { prs: prs, hours: hours }```

and ```avg = (g[:hours]/g[:prs].size).round(2)``` as well as ```g[:prs].each { |pr| puts "  ##{pr}: #{avg}" }```

I feel like I can navigate through most of your code, but these lines specifically I'm getting caught up on and I just don't understand what is taking place at these points in the program.

Comment: `inv_by_day` is a hash comprised of key-value pairs, so for the key that equals the value of the variable `day` (e.g., `"Wed"`)  `inv_by_day[day] = { prs: prs, hours: hours }` merely sets the value of that key to the hash `{ prs: prs, hours: hours }`.

Comment: `each` in `h.each do |day, g|` iterates over each key-value pair of `h`, assigning the key and value to the block variables `day` and `g` respectively. When `day` is assigned the value `"Mon"`, for example, `g` is set equal to `{ prs: ["123", "124"], hours: 21.05 }`. Therefore `g[:hours] #=> 21.05` (#=> meaning  `g[:hours]` equals `21.05`) and `g[:prs].size #=> ["123", "124"].size #=> 2`, so `(g[:hours]/g[:prs].size).round(2) #=> (21.05/2).round(2) #=> 10.525.round(2) #=> 10.53`.

Comment: Again, when the block variable `g` equals `{ prs: ["123", "124"], hours: 21.05 }`, `g[:prs] #=> ["123", "124"]`, so `g[:prs].each { |pr| puts "  ##{pr}: #{avg}" }` becomes `["123", "124"].each { |pr| puts "  ##{pr}: #{avg}" }`. Initially the block variable `pr` is assigned the value `"123"`, so the block calculation becomes `puts "  ##{"123"}: #{10.53}"` which becomes `puts "  #123: 10.53"` (where `avg #=> 10.53`, as explained in my previous comment). Note that in `##{pr}` the first pound sign is a literal character whereas the second is a special character that is part of `#{...}`.

Comment: Thank you Cary!!! I've been reading over this the past few days and it's starting to make more sense. I really appreciate you for taking the time to help me out!!

Comment: In case the use of [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) is not clear, `def invoices_by_day; DAYS.each_with_object({}) do |day, inv_by_day| ... end; end` is effectively shorthand for `def invoices_by_day; inv_by_day = {}; DAYS.each do |day| ... end; inv_by_day; end`.

Answer (score 1):

Hey – here you go –> https://gist.github.com/Oluwadamilareolusakin/4f147e2149aa97266cfbb17c5c118fbf

Made a gist for you that may help, let me know!

NOTE: Be careful with the `while true` so you don't run into an infinite loop

Here's it is for easy reference:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
def display_billable_hours(entries)
  entries.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{key}:"
    puts value
  end
end

def handle_input
  days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
  entries = {}

  days.each do |day|

    loop do
      p "Enter your invoice number for #{day}:"
      invoice_number = gets.chomp

      break if invoice_number.length > 0
    end

    loop do
      p "How many hours did you work on #{day}?:"
      hours_worked = gets.chomp
      break if hours_worked.length > 0
    end

    entries[day] = "##{invoice_number} - #{hours_worked} Hours"
  end
  
  entries
end

def do_audit
  entries = handle_input
  display_billable_hours(entries)
end

do_audit
```

Comment: Hey Damilare! Thanks for the help with this. This is close, however I would like the user to be able to input MULTIPLE PR #'s for each day and be able to break that loop somehow by entering "ok" or pressing "ENTER", then it would divide the amount of hours worked for the day evenly amongst the amount of PR #s entered by the user for each day of the week. Hope that clears things up a bit but this is very close to what I'm looking for!! Thank you again for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: @DamilareOlusakin: I would not use `while true; .... end`, but the more idiomatic `loop do; ... end `

Comment: Absolutely! @zspark94, happy to share. I'll make the adjustments for what you described

Comment: @user1934428 you're right, downsides of switching languages so often  sometimes you forget the tiny idiomatic things. Thanks for flagging!

Comment: If, for a given day, multiple invoice numbers are entered by the user, only the last is saved; that is, `invoice_number` is overwritten for each entry. Similar for hours, though I see no need for a loop there as only the total hours per day is needed.

Comment: Yepp that's true. The program here is designed to take one each i.e. `invoice_number` and `hours_worked` per day. However, Zach has mentioned he wants to be able to collect multiple invoices per day. The `loop do` blocks are there in my code to ensure that the user actually enters data before pressing enter and moving to the next prompt.